# Is that possible to create a virtual ground,for electrical purposes?

Tags: ground, grounding, earth

It might sound crazy, but I have seen many houses that doesn't supplied with electrical Ground (earth), and today there are many devices exist that need electrical ground.
I know that some people using metal water pipes, as grounding electrodes but actually I am Interested for a possible way of making a circuit that visualize the electrical grounding 
In terms of functionality and effects, including, noise reduction?

Comment: Hmm, there should be some earthed wall sockets in the kitchen or the bathroom of every house, can you use those?

Comment: It is extremely hard to virtualise safety using pretending grounds and even harder to virtualise bring-back-to-life and un-burn-down-house.

Comment: But believe me,there is no earthed wall socket in the room that I've mentioned,there are so many houses here,that doesn't have any earth connection,I've heard some people using some chemical material to virtualise earth?,it's weird,and that is why I am asking here.thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [Wikipedia's page on Earthing Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthing_system), You can see that Earth is usually just connected to Neutral at some point in the system. There are advantages and disadvantages to each system, involving different cost and levels of safety among other factors.

The scheme it appears you have is either the "TT" or "IT" topology. Although off the top of my head, there is another one it could be that isn't listed on that page. I would consult an electrician who will either inspect the system, contact the electrical supplier for the area, or both, to determine the best course of action.